# Рассылка юзерботом в телеграмм с помощью pyrogram

Tags: python, pyrogram

Помогите сократить кол-во строк в коде. Может, возможно сделать список `id`, чтобы рассылка была по нему? У меня не получается.
Так же, не понимаю, как прописать, чтобы выводилось id чата, если сообщение было туда отправлено.

---

```py
from pyrogram import Client, types, filters
from pyrogram.enums import ChatType
import time
from configparser import ConfigParser

api_id = 
api_hash = " "

interval = float(input('время задержки в секундах:____'))
text = 'текст'

client = Client(name='me_client', api_id=api_id, api_hash=api_hash)


async def main():
    async with client:
        async for dialog in client.get_dialogs():
            if dialog.chat.type in [ChatType.GROUP, ChatType.SUPERGROUP]:
                 await client.send_message(chat_id=-1001164, text=text)  
                 await client.send_message(chat_id=-1001670, text=text)  
                 await client.send_message(chat_id=-1001820, text=text)  
                 await client.send_message(chat_id=-1001693, text=text)  
               

                print('сообщение отправлено')
                time.sleep(interval)


client.run(main())
```

Comment: отлично, ща ответ напишу

Comment: А извините, если я напишу вопрос только по первому ответу, нормально будет? Или лучше не отвечать вообще? Просто второе я не знаю как решить к сожалению...

Comment: Выручите даже ответом на первый вопрос! )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По первому вопросу.

Это можно сделать с помощью массивов и цикла:

```py
from pyrogram import Client, types, filters
from pyrogram.enums import ChatType
import time
from configparser import ConfigParser

api_id = "<ВАШ ID ЗДЕСЬ>"
api_hash = " "

interval = float(input('время задержки в секундах:____'))
text = 'текст'

chat_ids = [-1001164, -1001670, -1001820, -1001693] # Здесь будет храниться все chat id для рассылки

client = Client(name='me_client', api_id=api_id, api_hash=api_hash)


async def main():
    async with client:
        async for dialog in client.get_dialogs():
            if dialog.chat.type in [ChatType.GROUP, ChatType.SUPERGROUP]:
                for chat_id in chat_ids: # перебираем id чатов...
                    # и отправляем туда сообщения:
                    await client.send_message(chat_id=chat_id, text=text)
               

                print('сообщение отправлено')
                time.sleep(interval)


client.run(main())
```

В этом коде, сначала создаётся массив со всеми `id` чатов, туда можно добавить не только группы, но любые валидные `id` чатов, хоть ЛС.

Потом, в цикле `for`, перебираются все `id` чатов, и отправляются сообщения.

---

Если что-то непонятно, спрашивайте.

Comment: По второму вопросу, к сожалению, не могу помочь, так как не знаю, как это делается. Можно отдельный вопрос создать по этому вопросу.

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: @Asya отметьте галочкой этот ответ и проголосуйте за (вверх), чтобы вопрос был решённым.

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос с тем, чтобы выводилось id чата, в которое бот отправил сообщение, тоже решен.

```
async def main():
    async with app:
        async for dialog in app.get_dialogs():
            if dialog.chat.type in [ChatType.GROUP, ChatType.SUPERGROUP]:
                for chat_id in chat_ids:
                    try:
                        await app.send_message(chat_id=chat_id, text=text)
                        print(f'сообщение отправлено в {chat_id}')
                    except Flood as e:
                        print(f'не удалось отправить сообщение в {chat_id}')
```

нужно импортировать ошибку. from pyrogram.errors import Flood
Вдруг кому-нибудь пригодится :)

Comment: Это восхитительно, что вы отвечаете на свой вопрос!